# quickest cpu instructions

Tags: cpu, instructions

Is there a list of the order of speed of instructions (this may be generally speaking at it will vary on the architecture)?  I was told years ago from my assembly professor that shift was the quickest.

How are +, -, *, / ordered?

Comment: But really who cares -- pipelining, branch prediction and cache performance will be by far the more important factors. A single, isolated CPU instruction on its own is a completely artificial construct that never even occurs in modern CPUs.

Comment: This is not a matter of caring for practical use like "pipelining, branch prediction..."  It's more for discussion of solving trivial questions like the "bit population count" and other software puzzles.

Comment: OK - well, good luck, I hope you get a useful answer!

Answer (score 2):

Agner Fog has a very nice list of instruction latencies and throughputs for x86 processors:

http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf

EDIT:

That said, you really have to be at this level of HPC to be able to make use of this information to improve performance.